# Problem with loading content in Nuxtjs generated dynamic page

Tags: preload, nuxtjs

i'm having trouble getting nuxt generated dynamic route pages to display content properly.
if anybody is interested in trying out my below demo app, you might see that for a very brief moment my expected ID gets displayed but then it disappears.
https://materially-info-static.onrender.com/item/5fbb06f5b088c500174cc9bd
in my console i'm getting the following warning about preloading but i don't know what it's really telling me. [image]
my nuxt config: https://github.com/lukkyjoe/materially-static/blob/main/nuxt.config.js#L8 based on following examples in these docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate
my vue file where i expected the ID to appear (and not flicker away): https://github.com/lukkyjoe/materially-static/blob/main/pages/item/_id.vue
would like to know what i'm doing wrong.